# Excel covert date from DDD MMM DD HH:MM:ss YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to convert this datetime format in MS Excel:

```
Sat Feb 09 09:58:15 PKT 2019
```

Into mysql date time format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss
```

So far custom date formating isn't working, any input would be appreciated.

---

***Example test data:***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula below to convert your time strings (here in A1) to Date/Time values in a helper column. Then set the cell format to match your requirements and replace the original column with the reformatted copy.

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1, 5, 6) & ", " & RIGHT(A1, 4)) + TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8))
```

Use *Copy/Paste Special > Values* to replace the formulas with real values.

Comment: Just tried, i think there might be an error, #VALUE! is shown in the value part, can you confirm

Comment: values start from A2, so that has been taken care of but still the same

Comment: I have slightly modified the formula. It should make no difference for now but it will help further down the line. Please enter this formula somewhere and advise what it returns. `=CODE(MID(A2,4,1))`. Also try `=DATEVALUE(MID(A1, 5, 6)` and `=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8)` and advise both results. The presumption I'm working on is that the spaces in your string aren't ordinary spaces. But might also be that your system doesn't recognise `=MID(A1, 5, 6)` as a date. We'll find out and make my solution work.

Comment: =MID(A2,5,6)&", "&RIGHT(A2,4) i.e. Feb 09, 2019
and =TIMEVALUE(MID(A2,12,8)) i.e. 1900-01-00 09:58:15
 separately works fine in different cells i.e. breaks down date and time respectively, however, I guess DATEVALUE at the top still gives out error

Comment: So, `DATEVALUE("Feb 09, 2019")` doesn't work. Can you juggle these components into a string that your system can interpret as a date (Try "09 Feb 2019" for example)? I suspect it has difficulty not with the sequence but with "Feb"?? Your answers didn't eliminate the requirement to know your answer to `=CODE(MID(A2,4,1))`. Please advise.

Comment: =CODE(MID(A2,4,1)) returns 00:00:00, however rest is the same, it couldn't wrap DATEVALUE

Comment: well I just fiddled around with data and googled some bits, now its competely within required format i.e. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS your answer provided a great starting point, many thanks!